# href inside "Load more" button doesn't bring more articles when pasting URL

Tags: html, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this site:

https://noticias.caracoltv.com/colombia

At the end you can find a "Cargar Más" button, that brings more news. So far so good. But, when inspecting that element it says it loads a link like this: `https://noticias.caracoltv.com/colombia?00000172-8578-d277-a9f3-f77bc3df0000-page=2`, as seen here:

[image]

The thing is, if I enter this into my browser, I get the same news I get if I just call the original website. Because of this, the only way I'm seeing I would be able to scrape the website is to create a script that recursively clicks. The thing is I need news until 2019, so it doesn't seem very feasible.

Also, when checking the event listeners I see this:

[image]

But I'm not sure how can I use that to my advantage.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to access older news through a link (or an API would be even better, but I didn't find any call to an API).

I'm currently using Python to scrape, but I'm in the investigation stage, so there's no code to show that's meaningful.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there's a nice api or other way to get the data in bulk. You will need to iterate through the "pages"/"load more" and then parse the html.

Will take a little time, but this code will do that for you.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
from dateutil import parser
import datetime
import pandas as pd

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

rows = []
endYear = 2019
continueLoop = True
page = 1
while continueLoop == True:

    url = f'https://noticias.caracoltv.com/colombia?00000172-8578-d277-a9f3-f77bc3df0000-page={page}'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    if page == 1:
        mainArticle = soup.find('div', {'class':'ListU'})
        jsonStr = str(mainArticle.find('script'))
        jsonStr = re.search('({.*})', jsonStr).group(1)
        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
        
        articlePublished = jsonData['datePublished']
        dt = parser.parse(articlePublished)
        
        print(f"{dt.day}-{dt.month}-{dt.year} : {jsonData['headline']}")
        rows.append(jsonData)
        
        subArticles = soup.find_all('li', {'class':'ListE-items-item'})
        for subArticle in subArticles:
            jsonStr = str(subArticle.find('script'))
            jsonStr = re.search('({.*})', jsonStr).group(1)
            jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
            
            articlePublished = jsonData['datePublished']
            dt = parser.parse(articlePublished)
            
            print(f"{dt.day}-{dt.month}-{dt.year} : {jsonData['headline']}")
            rows.append(jsonData)

    #get bottom articles
    loadMore = soup.find('ps-list-loadmore', {'class':'ListD'})
    articles = loadMore.find_all('li',{'class':'ListD-items-item'})
    for article in articles:
        if continueLoop == True:
            try:
                jsonStr = str(article.find('script'))
                jsonStr = re.search('({.*})', jsonStr).group(1)
                jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
                
                articlePublished = jsonData['datePublished']
                dt = parser.parse(articlePublished)
            except:
                headline = article.find('a', href=True)['title']
                articlePublished = article.find('div', {'PromoB-timestamp'})['data-timestamp']
                url = article.find('a', href=True)['href']
                
                jsonData = {
                    'headline':headline,
                    'datePublished':articlePublished,
                    'url':url}
            
            
            if endYear == dt.year:
                print('Done')
                continueLoop = False
            
            else:
                print(f"{dt.day}-{dt.month}-{dt.year} : {jsonData['headline']}")
                rows.append(jsonData)
            
    page += 1


df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
               @context  ...                                              video
0     http://schema.org  ...  {'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'Vi...
1     http://schema.org  ...  {'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'Vi...
2     http://schema.org  ...  {'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'Vi...
3     http://schema.org  ...                                                NaN
4     http://schema.org  ...  {'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'Vi...
                ...  ...                                                ...
6864  http://schema.org  ...  {'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'Vi...
6865  http://schema.org  ...  {'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'Vi...
6866  http://schema.org  ...  {'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'Vi...
6867  http://schema.org  ...  {'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'Vi...
6868  http://schema.org  ...  {'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'Vi...

[6869 rows x 15 columns]


print(df.columns)
Index(['@context', '@type', 'headline', 'description', 'articleBody',
       'articleSection', 'url', 'mainEntityOfPage', 'datePublished',
       'dateModified', 'author', 'publisher', 'image', 'keywords', 'video'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the through answer, seems to be what I'm looking for. When I have time to test the code I might have some questions, would you be able to answer them? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Just let me know.

Comment: Sorry, just now I was able to try to implement this. I'm having trouble with this line: `jsonStr = str(mainArticle.find('script'))`. After running it, its output is a 'None' string. Do you know what might be happening here? Checking the code I see no script tags in most articles. Maybe I could scrape the link and then get a list of links to eventually scrape

Answer (score 0):

Chech [Query String format @ wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), please.

You missing a `&` mark

Comment: But there's just one query parameter, which is `00000172-8578-d277-a9f3-f77bc3df0000-page=2`

Comment: They have javascript for processing the incoming page.
There're "Event Listeners" for click on "ps-link" that's wrapper for the button you click.
So, if you're doing web crawler's job, you've to merging the data by yourself.

Comment: Give "selenium" a try.

Comment: I found the function I added in my original post, but I'm not sure what can I do from here. Is there any way I can call said function from Python? (I'm not a scraping expert by any means) Thanks!